# Change header image based on multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multisite with two sites. An english and spanish version of the site. Right now the logo on my header.php is static.

```
<div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt=“Racing Logo” /></a></div>
```

How can I make this dynamic so that there is a different logo for each one?

What function would you call? Is there something that allows you check which multisite you are on to do an if statement or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php
$language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($language ){
case "fr":
    //echo "Display french language text in this page";
    include("index_fr.php");//include check session FR
    break;
case "es":
    //echo "Display Spanish language text in this page";
    include("index_it.php");
    break;
case "en":
    //echo "Display English language text in this page";
    include("index_en.php");
    break;        
default:
    //echo "Display English language text in this page";
    include("index_en.php");
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: You can put `case "en": default:` in one block, by the way `:D`